# PHP Mailer "Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto():" Error

Tags: php, ssl, phpmailer

I have a continuing SMTP problem with PHPMailer which is described here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure

I've looked at the errors given and, from what I can tell, this is the main culprit

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.mywebhost.com' did not match expected CN=`mail.mydomain.com' in /path/to/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 355

Other ideas/info.

1. I have an SSL installed and I've verified the legitimacy of it here: https://www.digicert.com/help/
2. This is a shared hosting environment.
3. It's a PHP 7 environment.
4. This is a subdomain setup.  So, the SSL is for **sub.mydomain.com** and the `$mail->Host` is **mail.mydomain.com**.  I don't know if that's relevant or not, but that's what it is.

I've already been through the PHPMailer documentation and I have no idea as to why this is still happening.  Valid SSL, no SMTP..... Any ideas on where I can check to fix this?

Comment: Unless you have a wildcard certificate, a certificate for `sub.mydomain.com` will not work for `mail.mydomain.com`. Starting with php 5.6, it starts authenticating the certificates [[src and options to fix/bypass](https://www.ecommercetemplates.com/support/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=95905)]

Comment: That link is awful, completely unclear. This whole thing is covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide linked to in the question and error messages.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for googling error messages instead of clicking links in posts. :-D

Comment: @Synchro: I'm not getting the `SSL operation failed with code 1.` error referenced in the PHPMailer documentation.  Where should I look next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You presumably have this set:

```
$mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';
```

but when you connect to that, it actually connects to your ISP's mail host (probably something like `mail.mywebhost.com`, which presents the `*.mywebhost.com` certificate), and so of course the name on the server's certificate you've got does not match. The correct solution to this is to change your `Host` property to use the real name of the mail server, as then the certificate will match, and you will have no mismatch errors:

```
$mail->Host = 'mail.mywebhost.com';
```

(you'll need to find out what the exact name should be). For this to work with your own certificate, you would need to be running your own mail server on its own IP, something you're not likely to get on shared hosting.

An alternative workaround also described in the troubleshooting guide is to disable certificate validation (as pre-5.6 PHP did) - but you should not do that. You know why this is failing, so you should fix it properly, not simply suppress the error.

Comment: I tried that and got `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (113)`.  Perhaps the issue has to do with the fact that an SSL was installed on the subdomain, but the main domain doesn't have an SSL right now.  I'm working on rectifying that, but does that seem like it would cause the given issue?

Comment: No. SSL is all about the receiver, not the client. That error means you have the wrong server name or your outbound SMTP is blocked. Check with your ISP.

Comment: Upon doing a bit more research, it seems that the "esmtpsa" part is indicating a successful TLS/SMTP connection (https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25998#p157973).  Is this right?